# How to iterate through a list and extract text between quotation marks using Python 2.7.10

Tags: python, regex, list, text-parsing

I'm trying to iterate through a long list (let's call it `url_list`) where each item looks like:

`<a href="https://www.example.com/5th-february-2018/" itemprop="url">5th February 2018</a>,`
`<a href="https://www.example.com/4th-february-2018/" itemprop="url">4th February 2018</a>,`
`<a href="https://www.example.com/3rd-february-2018/" itemprop="url">3rd February 2018</a>,`
`<a href="https://www.example.com/2nd-february-2018/" itemprop="url">2nd February 2018</a>,`

and so on.  I'd like to iterate through the list and keep only the text between the first two quotation marks, and throw away the rest - i.e:

`https://www.example.com/5th-february-2018/,`
`https://www.example.com/4th-february-2018/,`
`https://www.example.com/3rd-february-2018/,`
`https://www.example.com/2nd-february-2018/,`

So essentially I am trying to return a nice clean list of urls. I'm not having much luck iterating through the list and splitting on the quotation marks - is there a better way to do this?  Is there a way to throw away everything after the `itemprop=` string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Regex:

```
import re

url_list = ['<a href="https://www.example.com/5th-february-2018/" itemprop="url">5th February 2018</a>', '<a href="https://www.example.com/4th-february-2018/" itemprop="url">4th February 2018</a>']
for i in url_list:
    print re.search("(?P<url>https?://[^\s]+)/", i).group("url")
```

**Output:**

```
https://www.example.com/5th-february-2018
https://www.example.com/4th-february-2018
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the split function to split at " and then taking the 2nd entry from the resulting list?

```
urls=[]
for url_entry in url_list:
    url = url_entry.split('\"')[1]
    urls.append(url)
```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds a bit like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

If you were (or are) using [`BeautifulSoup`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) to parse your HTML it would become a lot easier:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_text = '''<a href="https://www.example.com/5th-february-2018/" itemprop="url">5th February 2018</a>
<a href="https://www.example.com/4th-february-2018/" itemprop="url">4th February 2018</a>
<a href="https://www.example.com/3rd-february-2018/" itemprop="url">3rd February 2018</a>
<a href="https://www.example.com/2nd-february-2018/" itemprop="url">2nd February 2018</a>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text)
urls = [x['href'] for x in soup.find_all("a")]
for url in urls:
    print(url)
# https://www.example.com/5th-february-2018/
# https://www.example.com/4th-february-2018/
# https://www.example.com/3rd-february-2018/
# https://www.example.com/2nd-february-2018/
```